# How to authenticate to WebSite with post request

Tags: c#, forms, http, authentication, post

i need to authenticat to this website: www.memrise.com with mail and password (not with google or facebook) using c#.
I already got an account in this website but i don't success in authentication thorugh c# code.
If somone can give me the exactly code to authenticate i ll be very gratefull.
(Sorry for my english but I'm an Italian student)

I tried with parameter in url request but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve this by using 'ASP.NET Identity'.

Reference Document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Memrise.com is not my web site , I wanna to authenticate to it from an external software